# Random variables coincide

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X,Y \in L^1$ and

$$\mathbb E(X \vert Y)=Y$$
$$\mathbb E(Y \vert X)=X.$$

Is it then true that $X=Y.$

This question came up because I can show it for $X,Y \in L^2$ by just computing $E((X-Y)^2)$ but I fail to see whether it also holds by just assuming integrability.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I can write a short proof that this is true if I put some time into it, but so far I'm coming up with a long proof.

Comment: . . . . . and now I find I answered this six years ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74692/conditional-expectation-and-almost-sure-equality